# Connecting 3 content types together entity reference/field collection - adding references in reverse?

Tags: entities

I have 3 content types:

**1. Client**
Fields: business name, description, contact name (all standard text fields)

**Field collection (called 'client campaign'): Fields: Entity reference field to campaign content type - so I can select campaign to tie this client to.**

**2. Campaign**
Fields: Campaign brief, campaign duration, campaign budget, campaign monthly hours (all standard text fields)

**Field collection (called 'collection publishers'): fields, publisher status (paid, live, dead, pending) [select list], publisher live date [pop up date], publisher payment amount [integer], Entity reference field to publisher field - so I can select publisher from drop down**

**3. Publishers**

Fields: website url, name, contact email, payment method (all standard text fields)

If I now:

1) add a client (create one client node)
2) add a campaign (create one campaign node)

I now can add publishers to my campaigns via the field collection added to this content type (collection publishers) This is set to unlimited to I can add as many as I want, in each one I can add in details for each publisher such as 'payment amount' 'live date' and all the other fields that are within this collection.

This all works fine but I need to be able to see all my publishers in one view with details of them and 'reverse' add them to a campaign all at once, perhaps via checkboxes. This will save loads of time. I tried an editable view but cannot seem to get this to work. I am not sure why. It is almost like I need to somehow write to the database without opening up the publisher node..

Was wondering it anyone out there can give me some pointers here or just tell me I am doing it all wrong! I don't mind which.

(the end goal here is to track publishers working across multiple campaigns and then I can see what's gong on at all times through views I'll create)

*ADDED A SCREEN SHOT OF THE 'LOGIC' BEHIND THIS!*

Thanks for any help in advance.
[image: Diagram of Drupal set up]

[image: How the campign node edit form looks currently]

[image: This is how I'd prefer this to look - using editable views here which would suffice I think]

Screengrab 2 shows how the current campaign node edit form looks - the field collection is showing the publisher nodes.

Screengrab 3 shows how I would probably like this to look, an editable view of publishers that I can assign a campaign to then save. However, this may not work as publishers can work over many campaigns...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need [Corresponding Entity References](http://drupal.org/project/cer):

> It syncs the entity reference between two entity types which have an entity reference to each other, so double editing entities is no longer needed. If one entity has a reference, the other entity also receives a reference to the saved entity if it is referenced in that entity.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the response. However, I don't just want to reference I need more than that. I want to reference a bunch of publishers AND specific information that only relates to that publisher and that specific campaign. For example, Publisher A might work on Campaign B for $100, Campaign C for $12 and Campaign D for $459. I need to also somehow 'store' this information on the campaign node so I can reference it through a view for my records. This is a great module there's a very good tutorial for it here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g_nBEj0yGa4

Answer (score -1):

I do all that you want with the following modules:

- entityconnect - edit entityreference in content
- entityreference - call node is an nother content into creatting content
- field_collection - call entityreference in ones
- field_collection_table - option view display table in another necessary views (when u want display untimited entityreference field in views)
- field_collection_views - diplay all content of field collection to views into node